# Remove all symbols except the comma

Tags: r, string

I am a beginner in R. I have a data.frame looks like this:

```
religion
list(\"christian\"),list()                                   
list(\"jewish\"),list()                                                                             
list(\"christian\"),list(\"catholic\", \"episcopal\")        
list(\"christian\"),list(\"evangelical\", \"lutheran\")       
list(\"christian\"),list(\"evangelical\", \"lutheran\")
....
```

The type of this vector is chr
This is what I want to be:

```
religion
christian
jewish
christian, catholic, episcopal
christian, evangelical, lutheran
christian, evangelical, lutheran
```

I want to delete the list() and \" but keep the religion names and separate them by comma. How can I do this in R

Comment: Can you use `dput` to show us a snippet of your actual code.  What you have there doesn't create an object for us to work with.

Comment: have a look at `?regex`.   However, it is not clear what you have and what you would like it to be.  Do you just want it to _display_ without the quotes?  If so, have a look at `cat(..)` and `print(.., quote=FALSE)`

Comment: You data looks like the output of `deparse`, so `parse` might be the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the structure of your data, but a `gsub` would be one way to go about this...

```
#  Data
str <- ":215H@#e5.:l[l[}o%^&*3,-7 55W(o]]43r6759l::~!1d424`$£"
#  Remove everything except spaces, commas and letters
gsub( "[^,a-zA-Z\\s]" , "" , str , perl = TRUE )
#[1] "Hello, World"
```

Matches any character except, commas, spaces and lower and uppercase letters. Bear in mind this leaves commas in place *wherever* they appear in the text, and not just between word boundaries for instance.

If you need to apply this to *each column* of a `data.frame` and return a `data.frame` I'd use `lapply` and `do.call` (in the example below I assume that your `data.frame` is called `mydf` )...

```
clean <- lapply( mydf , gsub , pattern = "[^,a-zA-Z\\s]" , replacement = "" , perl = TRUE )
clean.df <- do.call( data.frame , clean )
```

e.g.

```
#  Make a data.frame with text containing punctuation
x <- rep( str , 4 )
mydf <- data.frame( a = x , b = x , c = x )

#  List of clean columns
clean <- lapply( mydf , gsub , pattern = "[^,a-zA-Z\\s]" , replacement = "" , perl = TRUE )

#  Coerce to data.frame
do.call( data.frame , clean )
#             a            b            c
#1 Hello, World Hello, World Hello, World
#2 Hello, World Hello, World Hello, World
#3 Hello, World Hello, World Hello, World
#4 Hello, World Hello, World Hello, World
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. First I use df$religion<-gsub("list","",df$religion) to delete all "list" and then delete all the symbols except the comma.